# Is it not possible to give an image more than one transition?

Tags: css, transition

So i made a php form with chekboxes which i show as images. Now i gave them a transition thing witch goes from opacity 0.5 to 1 if you click on them
now i would have liked to change the border color from red to yellow but if I combine those 2 transition only one seems to work. The opacity is there but it instantly goes from 0.5 to 1 and not in a 2 second timespan

Here is my css with 2 transitions:

```
img {

    width: 100%;
    max-width: 390px;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 250px;
    margin: -3px;
    border-radius:15px;
    transition:opacity 2s ease;
    opacity: 0.5;

    transition: border 1s ease;
    border: red 3px solid;

    }
```

now there is a little bit more of important code which I cannot display cause the nice stackoverflow editor does not accept it as css

I still hope someone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple transitions by seperating them with a comma on the same `transition:` rule.

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 390px;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 250px;
    margin: -3px;
    border-radius:15px;
    transition:opacity 2s ease, border 1s ease;
    opacity: 0.5;
    border: red 3px solid;
}
```

In the case you have multiple transitions, all with the same duration and timing function, you can use the shorthand `all`:

```
transition: all 2s ease;
```

**[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/sht7dtyv/)**